# Android Studio Choose Wrong build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

> How can I solve this?

android   app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blueehr.bluenotes"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true



    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            proguardFiles fileTree('proguard')
                    .include("*.pro")
                    .asList()
                    .toArray()

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                changeAPKName("xxx", variant, defaultConfig, "R")
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true

            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                changeAPKName("xxx", variant, defaultConfig, "D")
            }
        }


        debugAdvance {
            initWith debug
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            proguardFiles fileTree('proguard')
                    .include("*.pro")
                    .asList()
                    .toArray()
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                changeAPKName("xxx", variant, defaultConfig, "Dadvance")
            }

        }
    }
```

and if I select the default build variant as debug [image: debug]

and assumed android studio build apk with a custom name of ***xxx......D.apk*** .
but always android studio build apk with ***xxx......Dadvance.apk*** from ***debugAdvance***  variant and not from ***debug*** .
any error in my code?

Comment: Do you want build.gradle ? cause your build.gradle different from other

Comment: @Ashish why gradle build different apk?

Comment: Do you want to change your apk name ? or what i cant understand your question Properly

Comment: @Ashish if I select `debug`  as  variant type,  gradle should build apk with custom 
 name xxx.....D.apk

Comment: and @Ashish if i select `debugAdvance `  as  variant type,  gradle should build apk with custom 
 name xxx.....Dadvance .apk

Comment: but if I selected debug ,it create xxx.....Ddvance.apk not xxx.....D.apk   y?